# Getting more useful data from a lookup on a many-to-many relationship in Fauna

Tags: relational-database, faunadb, document-database, fql.multiquery

I have a `users` collection and an `invitations` collection. Users can invite multiple users. Records in the `invitations` collection document these invites. Each record in `invitations` is shaped like this:

```
"data": {
  "sponsor": Ref(Collection("users"), "344418396214919370"),
  "sponsee": Ref(Collection("users"), "345390249407414474")
}
```

The sponsor is the inviter and the sponsee is the invitee. Both reference a user in the `users` collection.

**I'd like to know the most efficient way in FQL (minimum reads) to get the list of users that a particular user has invited, and some basic information about them.**

The indexes I have setup are `user_by_email` and `sponsee_by_sponsor`. I also have a Function which gets a user by email called (you guessed) `getUserByEmail`.

What I have tried so far is:

```
Paginate(
  Match(
    Index('sponsee_by_sponsor'),
    Call(Fn('getUserByEmail'), 'sponsor@email.com')
  ),
)
```

Which gets me what I want but only in user Refs:

```
data: [
    Ref(Collection("users"), "345390249407414474"),
    Ref(Collection("users"), "345390805049934027")
  ]
```

Above is the result of the query, which are all the users that have been invited by `sponsor@email.com`. But they are refs and I would like more information about each of these users, without having to make another read. I'm very new to FQL, so any help would be welcome.

### ***Update***

As per a request from the comment, here are the definitions of my indexes and Function:

[image]

A typical User document is shaped like this:

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("users"), "344418396214919370"),
  "ts": 1665703164070000,
  "data": {
    "email": "sponsor@email.com",
    "name": "Sponsor Name",
  }
}
```

Being able to get the email and name of the sponsees (rather than the Refs) is what is desired in as few reads as possible.

Comment: Can you share the definitions of the index and function? And can you provide a sample user document and what "basic" information you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are the most efficient way to find documents in collections. But sometimes, the simplicity of indexes makes isolating documents hard, and that's where `Filter` or `Reduce` can help. Applying these functions is easy, but applying them efficiently requires a good understanding of the workflow and desired results. For example, you could `Filter` an entire collection, but that uses the "table scan" strategy, which is slow. But you can apply `Filter` to matches from a `Match` or the items from `Paginate`.

## Efficiency improvement

Your `getUserByEmail` UDF is less efficient than it could be. It calls `Get` to fetch the reference and then selects the reference from the fetched document. The index provides that reference directly.

Since `Match` returns a set, which can contain 0 or more entries, you were likely using `Get` to materialize the first match. However, you can do this:

```
Select(["data", 0], Paginate(Match(Index("user_by_email"), "<email>")))
```

That query only reads the matching index entries. Since the index has `unique: true`, the set can only contain one entry. That means the `Select` call only needs to fetch item 0.

## Fetch sponsee details

To return `sponsee` details, you must compose the response appropriately. The `Let` function is your friend for this task since it allows you to capture intermediate values and act on them.

For example:

```
Let(
  {
    email: "<email>",
    user_ref: Select(
      ["data", 0],
      Paginate(Match(Index("user_by_email"), Var("email"))),
    ),
    sponsees: Match(Index("sponsee_by_sponsor"), Var("user_ref")),
  },
  Map(
    Paginate(Var("sponsees")),
    Lambda(
      "sponsee_ref",
      Let(
        {
          sponsee: Get(Var("sponsee_ref")),
        },
        {
          name: Select(["data", "name"], Var("sponsee")),
          email: Select(["data", "email"], Var("sponsee")),
        }
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The first argument to the first `Let` lets us build up the values needed for the success of the query.

Since the `sponsees` value is a set, the second argument in the first `Let` is the expression that gives us the desired result. The `sponsees` set gets paginated, and `Map` applies the `Lambda` function to each entry in the page (the sponsee references). The `Lambda` accepts each sponsee reference, fetches the full sponsee document, and then composes an object containing fields for only the sponsee's `name` and `email` values.

Once you see how this all comes together, you should find it reasonably easy to modify the query to include/exclude fields or perform other operations.

Comment: Thanks for this. This does indeed seem to work although it's taken a bit of reading to fully understand it. The first part is relatively straight forward for me, but the part where it uses `Map` and `Lambda` required me to look into those a bit further. The only issue I can see with this is what happens in a situation where a Ref points to a place that no longer exists. Let's say a user was deleted from the database; surely this whole query would fail as soon as a broken Ref was found?

Comment: Yes. My example does not address broken relations. While that is related to your question, how to deal with broken relations is a separate question. Essentially, you'd replace the `Get` in the `Let` expression with `If(Exists(Var("sponsee_ref")), Get(Var("sponsee_ref")), <what to do when sponsee does not exist>)`. You'd need to decide what an appropriate result would be when the relation is broken.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks for your answer and further info. I've upvoted but will mark as correct as it effectively answers the question.